# Table text become italic

Tags: tables

Why in second column "Description" is italic for the following code?

```
\begin{table}%[h]
\caption{The logical notations of BAN-logic }
\label{tab:1}       
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{1.6cm}| >{\left} m{6cm}}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Notation &  Description   \\ \hline \hline

\hline
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline            
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete, self contained document with your table, which will reproduce your problem.

Comment: your code snippet has many errors. if i remove them, i cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: Probably, because when TeX recovers after `>{\left}` (which is incorrect) it is still in math mode when it typesets "Description".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can improve your tabular a little bit with some extra packages, nothing extraordinary, of course. You get (probably) the manual of each by typing `texdoc packagename` on the commandline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}%[h]
\caption{The logical notations of BAN-logic }
\label{tab:1}       
\begin{tabular}{>{\Centering}m{1.6cm} | >{\RaggedLeft} m{6cm}}\\\toprule
Notation &  Description   \\\midrule

  Content 1 & Content 2\\\bottomrule


\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]